# How to organize includes for a header-only library that wants to expose mutually recursive functions?

Tags: c++, include

I'm creating a library such that there are functions that look like this:

```
template <typename T> bool A (int, int, T&);
template <typename T> bool B (int, int, T&);

template <typename T> 
class IFoo {
    virtual T funct(int i) = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class FooA : IFoo<T> {
    virtual T funct(int i) override {
        if (!i) {
            return FooB(i-1);
        } else {
            return T(0);
        }
    }
};

template <typename T>
class FooB : IFoo<T> {
    virtual T funct(int i) override {
        if (!i) {
            return FooA(i-1);
        } else {
            return T(1);
        }
    }
};
```

These definitions require splitting up the code into declaration and definition parts so as to allow both procedures to be aware of each other, and then have access to implementations at the same time.

But my question is, how can I expose these functions in a clear manner (meaning, how should I write a header to encapsulate the dependency include pattern) while also making it easy to add new "functions" or other mutually recursive components (meaning, functions or derived classes) so that users of the components will not have to manually order the include of the declaration headers and the definition headers?

Comment: That code doesn't seem right. `FooB` and `FooA` are not generally convertible to `T`, are they?

Comment: @KerrekSB This is just a minimal example to express the problem. The real application is expression evaluation procedures and recursive descent parsing functions. Both require mutual recursion between functions because expression and non-terminal rules can contain other expression and non-terminal rules respectively. For these, we use delegating class with a polymorphic interface and templated mutually recursive functions, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By separating declarations from implementations.

```
template <typename T>
class IFoo {
    virtual T funct(int i) = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class FooA : IFoo<T> {
    virtual T funct(int i) override;  // declaration only...
};

template <typename T>
class FooB : IFoo<T> {
    virtual T funct(int i) override {
        if (!i) {
            return FooA<T>(i-1);
        } else {
            return T(1);
        }
    }
};


// implementation here - once all type information is available
template<typename T>
T FooA<T>::funct(int i) {
    if (!i) {
        return FooB<T>(i-1);
    } else {
        return T(0);
    }
}
```

> how to organise headers?

Here's one way:

**detail/ifoo.hpp**

```
#pragma once
template <typename T>
class IFoo {
    virtual T funct(int i) = 0;
};
```

**detail/fooa.hpp**

```
#pragma once
#include "ifoo.hpp"

template <typename T>
class FooA : IFoo<T> {
    virtual T funct(int i) override;
};
```

**detail/foob.hpp**

```
#pragma once
#include "ifoo.hpp"

template <typename T>
class FooB : IFoo<T> {
    virtual T funct(int i) override;
};
```

**detail/impl_fooa.hpp**

```
#pragma once
#include "fooa.hpp"
#include "foob.hpp"
template<typename T>
T FooA<T>::funct(int i) {
    if (!i) {
        return FooB<T>(i-1);
    } else {
        return T(0);
    }
}
```

**detail/impl_foob.hpp**

```
#pragma once
#include "fooa.hpp"
#include "foob.hpp"
template<typename T>
virtual T FooB<T>::funct(int i) override {
    if (!i) {
        return FooA<T>(i-1);
    } else {
        return T(1);
    }
}
```

finally your header

**library.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include "detail/ifoo.hpp"
#include "detail/fooa.hpp"
#include "detail/foob.hpp"
#include "detail/impl_fooa.hpp"
#include "detail/impl_foob.hpp"
```

Comment: Right, but I'm also asking is how to organize the separation of each part and how to package them back up into a final header. There are about 10 mutually recursive procedures, and how would the gradual "adding" process of another be done? Just need that one tip.

Comment: @VermillionAzure what do you mean by "separate" and "add them back up"? Are you talking about one include file that includes several others, or a pre-make tool that generates code?

Comment: I mean, "How can you encapsulate the declaration and definitions that must use other declaration and definitions into their own header files," and then, "How can you expose a single header to users of those functions to hide the complexity of the include dependency pattern required for the mutually recursive functions/headers?"

Answer (score 1):

Keep strongly connected components together in a single header.